# На чем всё это написано?

Tags: jquery

Недавно заметил музыкальный сервис zvooq.ru, там всё так плавно, со всех сторон вылетают блоки... вобщем мне очень понравилось как это сделано, чего только стоит раздел "Волны"..

Кто-то в курсе с помощью чего вообще они добились таких эффектов? `jQuery`?

Comment: Не знаю что именно там использовалось, но, во всяком случае на главной, в чистом виде - jquery нет

Comment: Тогда может javascript?

Comment: А какая по вашему разница между jquery и javascript?

LOL - javascript это язык программирования, jquery - фреймворк

Comment: Проект хороший, читал про него где-то, потому мне кажется, что это не вопрос, а вирусная реклама =)

Comment: Не, я проект на хабре заметил, а в будущем планируют сделать проект со схожим функционеалом, вот и заинтересовался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Libraries API](https://zvooq.ru/static/js/welcome.c84c7bbf.js). Довольно занимательный скрипт.

P.S. Автору спасибо, как нибудь на досуге поизучаю.